# Update 'like' count in Rails with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've researched many of the other SO posts on this topic but could not seem to find one that matches my scenario.

My site has posts, which can be liked by users, incrementing the like counts. If I do this without Ajax and just use a page refresh, the counter increments properly and the button changes color, as desired. In fact, my Ajax code is changing the color of the button upon click, it's just that the like count isn't incrementing.

The server logs also seem to show that the request is being processed as JS and persisted to the database, so why is the count not being refreshed?

#### likes_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @like = @post.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {}
    end
end

def destroy
    @like = Like.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id], user_id: params[:user_id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {}
    end
end
```

#### _like_post.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.already_likes?(post) %>
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{post.likes.count}".html_safe, like_path(post_id: post.id, user_id: current_user.id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default stat-item active', id: "unlike-post", remote: true %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{post.likes.count}".html_safe, likes_path(post_id: post.id), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-default stat-item', id: "like-post", remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

#### create.js.erb

```
$("#unlike-post").show();
```

#### destroy.js.erb

```
$("#like-post").show();
```

## Edit:

I was originally encountering an error with the solution because my `likes` routes were not nested within the posts. I changed that and also changed the subsequent like and unlike paths to reflect the nesting change (to `post_likes_path` and `post_like_path`, respectively). I also tweaked the destroy method in my likes controller to `@like = Like.find(params[:id]).destroy`. Finally, I passed @like as a variable in the unlike path so that that whole path reads: `post_like_path(@like, post_id: post.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rerender the partial file `_like_post.html.erb` when you like or unlike the post through `create.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb`

You have `$("#unlike-post").show();` but it does not update anything in the page; what `.show()` only does (equivalently) is change the css of the element into `display: block`.

Having said these, the following should make it work

_like_post.html.erb

```
<div id='like-post-container'>
  <% if current_user.already_likes?(post) %>
      <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{post.likes.count}".html_safe, like_path(post_id: post.id, user_id: current_user.id), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default stat-item active', id: "unlike-post", remote: true %>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{post.likes.count}".html_safe, likes_path(post_id: post.id), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-default stat-item', id: "like-post", remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#like-post-container').html('<%= j render partial: "likes/like_post", locals: {post: @post} %>');
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#like-post-container').html('<%= j render partial: "likes/like_post", locals: {post: @like.post} %>');
```

Note that this approach will recreate the elements. If you have JS bindings on these elements, it will be removed, and might not work properly. If you have bindings, then you'll have to update the count value directly and not like my implementation above.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error with this. `undefined local variable or method "post"`. Is this because it's a partial and I need to define for JS what 'post' is?

Comment: Updated. now passing the `post` variable.

Comment: I think we are very close, but now I'm getting a routing issue. The server is saying `(No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"likes", :post_id=>928, :user_id=>1} missing required keys: [:id])`. I thought the parameters were being passed properly?

Comment: I think that error is related to your `routes.rb`. Your 3rd line above in `_like_post.html.erb` doesn't really have an ID passed to it as part of params (you're only passing post_id and user_id), so I do not think my answer would have affected it. You are not using RESTful convention for create and destroy actions so your routes should be something like `controller :likes do post 'create'; delete 'destroy'` (note that there is no id passed)

Comment: I had the same issue @scobo - I resolved it by creating `likes/create.html.erb` and `likes/destroy.html.erb`, but now I'm getting redirected the to individual like page... Did you figure out what was happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just update your js.erb fields to update the count number

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#unlike-post").html("<%= j "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{@post.likes.count}".html_safe %>")
$("#unlike-post").show();
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#like-post").html("<%= j "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>#{@like.post.likes.count}".html_safe %>")
$("#like-post").show();
```

Hope this help. :)

Comment: Just tried this and I'm getting the same error as the other post (which may or may not be unrelated to the question). The error is `(No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"likes", :post_id=>928, :user_id=>1} missing required keys: [:id])`

Comment: Even after making the adjustments in my edit, I unfortunately couldn't get this solution to work.

Comment: That is another issue. So because "like_path" requires key :id so i suggest 2 options in this case.
1. You can pass fake id to the path like_path(id: 1, .....) because you don't need this param in your action.
2. (recommended) find the like of current_user for the post pass it to the path  like_path(the_like_object, .....)